# customtkinter Radiobutton does not change IntVar value

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I try to run the following code. The main issue is, that I don't understand why **when I make a different radiobutton active it doesn't change the entry `placeholder_text`**.

I expected `self.choice_var` value to change, but it does not. I thought that `.mainloop()` actually should ensure the repetitiveness of the code, but it seems I get it wrong.

The main idea is to make a number of a different `radiobutton` options. Each option has to have a different amount of `entry` boxes shown. At this stage, I have two `radiobuttons` and two `entry` boxes.

As far as my knowledge allows, the code at this moment only changes the `placeholder_text`. The empty `entry` box with `None` should be inactive (not yet implemented), but ideally not to be shown at all (to figure out how).

But as I already marked it: *firstly I want to understand why the `placeholder_text` values in the `entry` boxes do not change?* Please advise.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("light")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class Interface(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title('Tool')
        self.geometry(f"{900}x{600}")

        # configure grid layout
        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), weight=0) 
        
        # configure radiobutton frame
        self.radiobutton_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=250)
        self.radiobutton_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nw')
        self.radiobutton_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.radiobutton_frame, text='Choose option:')
        self.radiobutton_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, sticky='')
        
        self.choice_var = tk.IntVar()
        
        def selected_param_entry():
            return ('Param 1.1', 'Param 1.2') if self.choice_var.get() == 0 else ('Param 2.1', None)

        param1, param2 = selected_param_entry()

        self.first_option_btn = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, text='Option 1', variable=self.choice_var, value=0, command=selected_param_entry)
        self.first_option_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='n')
        self.second_option_btn = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, text='Option 2', variable=self.choice_var, value=1, command=selected_param_entry)
        self.second_option_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='n')

        # configure entry frame
        self.entry_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=250)
        self.entry_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='sw')
        self.entry_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.entry_frame, text='Parameters: ')
        self.entry_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, sticky='')
        
        self.entry_param1_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.entry_frame, placeholder_text=param1)
        self.entry_param1_entry.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='sw')
        self.entry_param2_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.entry_frame, placeholder_text=param2)
        self.entry_param2_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=0, sticky='sw')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Interface()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: *Why* would you expect the `placeholder_text` to change?  You specify the parameter once when initially creating the Entries, and do absolutely nothing to change it later.  You never even assign new values to the variables (`param1`/`param2`) that the parameter was set from - not that doing so would have any effect on the widgets.

Comment: does this help? `self.choice_var = tk.IntVar(value=1)`

Comment: no toyota, the problem has been correctly identified by @jasonharper, the root cause is the belief that using a variables (e.g. as argument to a function) implies keeping a reference to that variable, no to the object the variable references. It's a misconception of how variables work in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic link between the placeholder text of either `CTkEntry` components and the radio buttons, you need to implement it.

Try this instead, this code dynamically configures `CTkEntry`'s `placeholder` from within the callback function given to the radio buttons:

```
def selected_param_entry():
    param1, param2 = ('Param 1.1', 'Param 1.2') if self.choice_var.get() == 0 else ('Param 2.1', '')
    self.entry_param1_entry.configure(placeholder_text=param1)
    self.entry_param2_entry.configure(placeholder_text=param2)

self.first_option_btn = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, text='Option 1', variable=self.choice_var, value=0, command=selected_param_entry)
self.first_option_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='n')
self.second_option_btn = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, text='Option 2', variable=self.choice_var, value=1, command=selected_param_entry)
self.second_option_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='n')

# configure entry frame
self.entry_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, width=250)
self.entry_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='sw')
self.entry_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.entry_frame, text='Parameters: ')
self.entry_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, sticky='')

self.entry_param1_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.entry_frame)
self.entry_param1_entry.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky='sw')
self.entry_param2_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.entry_frame)
self.entry_param2_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=0, sticky='sw')

selected_param_entry()
```

(anything above `selected_param_entry()` doesn't change (except maybe `f"{900}x{600}"` which could be advantageously written `'900x600'`)